# Set a value at NOW() with Propel

Tags: propel

I would like to rewrite this kind query in Propel:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_datetime_field = NOW()
WHERE my_id = 99;
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have a few options:

**Option 1**:

Assuming that you define your column as TIMESTAMP in your schema.xml, you can do this:

```
$row->setMyDateTimeField('now');
```

[Read more about Propel's Temporal Clumns...](http://propelorm.org/documentation/reference/active-record.html#temporal-columns)

**Option 2**:

You can set up a hook in your class that will be called everytime a row is updated in the table:

```
<?php
class MyTable extends BaseMyTable
{
    public function preUpdate(PropelPDO $con=null)
    {
       $this->setMyDateTimeField('now');
       return true;
    }
....
```

[Read more about Propel's Behaviours](http://propelorm.org/documentation/06-behaviors.html#pre-and-post-hooks-for-save-and-delete-methods)

**Conclusion**

Option 2 is more beneficial if you have more than one piece of logic that updates the table, both/all the updates would benefit from this update

Comment: `$this->setMyDateTimeField('now')` is not equivalent to SQL `NOW()`, as Propel will parse it as DateTime, meaning it would be the time on the server, not the time on the database server.